# iOS Modal dialog via storyboard UITabBarController

Tags: objective-c, ios5, storyboard, xcode-storyboard

[image: storyboard]

I'm looking to understand the "best" way to transition to UITabBarController D (the main interface in my application) from either A or B - conditionally going through C.

Meaning I'd like all of the following to be valid.

```
A -> C -> D
A -> B -> C -> D
A -> B -> D
A -> D
```

C is a modal dialog which basically asks the user for a piece of missing information if they don't have it set in their profile.

I've tried:

1. Using a triggered modal segue from D -> C in the viewDidLoad function of D:

   ```
   ([self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"ShowNumberDialog" sender:self];)
   ```
2. Programatically displaying C as a modal on D in the viewDidLoad function:

   ```
   (void)viewDidLoad
   {
       [super viewDidLoad];

       NSString *deviceNumber = [[UserModel sharedSingleton] deviceNumber];
       if ([deviceNumber isEqual:[NSNull null]]) {

           UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
           UIViewController *vc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"NumberDialog"];
           [vc setModalPresentationStyle:UIModalPresentationFullScreen];

           NSLog(@"Showing device number dialog");
          [self presentModalViewController:vc animated:NO];
       }
   }
   ```

Neither of these, plus uncountably other "hacky" attempts I've made seem to be working. So I assume I'm not understanding something fundamental about the way I'm supposed to do this. Can someone please recommend a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try moving the code you have in `ViewDidLoad` to `ViewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated`. What may be happening is that you are trying to push a modal dialog into the program while the transition to Tab Page D is still occurring which means the application disregards your request to open the modal dialog C as it continues to load D. `ViewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated` is called when your view is finally visible to the user and fully loaded.

Comment: Glad it worked! If you don't, you should definitely check the output window of the XCode debugger. You would have noticed a message along the lines of "Can't push a view while another view is being pushed" or something similar. Sometimes the output window is helpful!

Answer (score 0):

So basically I don't understand the "performSegue..." from D to C. A TabBar is triggered by the user, so he has to tap the icon to come to this controller.

I would place C between B and D. Check if the informations are complete - if no --> Segue to C, otherwise to D.

Do you see problems in this approach?